# Need to get text outlines or text drawing shapes from text with framework font in c#

Tags: c#, .net, graphics, vector-graphics

I have instructions to draw text on Graphics. Like string, font details. 
Now, I want to get shapes from those instruction. may be list of points to draw character 'A'.

My AIM is to convert text drawing into shape drawing. Need to avoid use of DrawString API (Nothing wrong with APIs, it is just my need.

Sample Code:

```
GraphicsPath path = new GraphicsPath();

path.StartFigure();

path.AddString("Sample Text", new FontFamily("arial"),
  1, 50, new Point(0, 0),
  StringFormat.GenericTypographic);

path.CloseFigure();
PointF[] pt=path.PathPoints;
```

Comment: Where's the code that you tried already?

Comment: I have updated my question, it shows only text outlines. I need to filled text shapes. not just oulines

Comment: @PradeepMMalage: That's to be expected. Text is represented by an outline path. If you want to draw it filled, you have to *fill* that path instead of stroking it.

Answer (score 0):

GDI is a raster library. It doesn't work with vector graphics.

If you're trying to write to an SVG you're much better off using a library like this one: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3751/An-SVG-framework-in-C-and-an-SVG-GDI-bridge.

This library promises to link GDI to SVG so that you don't need to worry about it.

Comment: Basically, I am trying get the instructions to draw. currently below line is giving me list of points to draw. But the output is outlines of the text..
 text.PointF[] pt=path.PathPoints;

Comment: So why not just render the solid text over the top? After you're done with the path? Perhaps I'm not understanding the question properly?

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I am trying convert vector graphics from text. like text with font to svg.

Comment: Oh I see what you're trying to achieve. Okay... so the problem I think you're going to have is that you're working with a raster library. Svg files are basically markup. So you need to write tags in your svg. If I were you I would use a library like this one: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3751/An-SVG-framework-in-C-and-an-SVG-GDI-bridge

Comment: Thanks, you are right. I must add svg tags but .net framework does not give me glyph information. I need to have each character glyph information so that I can use those information to form svg tags.

Comment: You have the font, size and position... is this not enough?

Comment: I can create text tags in svg but some of the windows font does not supported on browser so I thought I will get character glyph from text. And then I will just add <path tags in svg to view.

Comment: So then your question is how to get a glyph from the text?